# How do I put a parameter to a function whose return is inside a re.sub()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, parameters, regex-group

```py
import re

def one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func(m, type_of_date_unit_used):
    input_text = m.group()

    print(repr(input_text))

    if (type_of_date_unit_used == "year"): a = "YYYY-mm-dd"
    elif (type_of_date_unit_used == "month"): a = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    elif (type_of_date_unit_used == "day"): a = "yyyy-mm-DD"
    
    return a


def identify_one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date(input_text, type_of_date_unit_used = "day"):
    date_capture_pattern = r"([123456789]\d*-[01]\d-[0-3]\d)(\D*?)"

    input_text = re.sub(date_capture_pattern, one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func, input_text, re.IGNORECASE) #This is the line

    return input_text


input_text = "En 2012-06-12 empezo y termino en algun dia del 2023"
print(identify_one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date(input_text, "month"))
```

I need to pass the parameter `"month"` when calling the `one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func` function in the `re.sub()`

The output that I need with this parameter

```
"En yyyy-MM-dd empezo y termino en algun dia del 2023"
```

Comment: you want to replace `"2012-06-12"` as `"yyyy-MM-dd"`?

Comment: you forget to add parameter `one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func(input_text, type_of_date_unit_used)` and remove this line `input_text = m.group()`

Comment: @Ramesh This is a simplified program so that it remains in the stack question, however the important thing is how to pass that parameter in that function that is inside one of the parameters of re.sub()

Comment: just directly pass the parameters...i have added the code in answers section

Comment: First, back up a step and describe what you want this program to do. What should the user see as they interact with it? What will the user type in and what will the result be?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I got it done by using a lambda function that calls the function in an indirect way

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly pass the parameters inside `re.sub`.

```
import re


def one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func(m, type_of_date_unit_used):
    print(repr(m))

    if type_of_date_unit_used == "year":
        a = "YYYY-mm-dd"
    elif type_of_date_unit_used == "month":
        a = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    elif type_of_date_unit_used == "day":
        a = "yyyy-mm-DD"

    return a


def identify_one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date(input_text, type_of_date_unit_used="day"):
    date_capture_pattern = r"\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}"
    pattern_matched = ''.join(re.findall(date_capture_pattern, input_text))
    input_text = re.sub(date_capture_pattern,
                        one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func(pattern_matched, type_of_date_unit_used),
                        input_text,
                        re.IGNORECASE)  # This is the line

    return input_text


input_text = "En 2012-06-12 empezo y termino en algun dia del 2023"
print(identify_one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date(input_text, "month"))
>>> '2012-06-12'
>>> En yyyy-MM-dd empezo y termino en algun dia del 2023
```

Comment: The main problem with this is that the `one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func()` function receives all this `"En 2012-06-12 empezo y termino en algun dia del 2023"` string and not this other `"2012-06-12"` string.

Comment: so you want `"2012-06-12"` to passed in `one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func()` instead of `En 2012-06-12 empezo y termino en algun dia del 2023`?

Comment: I want the re.sub() function to continue to capture, and that capture group that the re.sub() function manages to capture, pass it to the function whose return is the replacement, maybe I'm wrong, but I think so you pass input_text directly to prevent re.sub() from doing its process capture

Comment: you cant pass the value the before it is existed... `re.sub` substitues only if `one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func()` is called. but the function needs a parameter which does not exists.

Comment: You are right, I had not thought of it that way, it is true that I cannot load a value that does not exist yet in a parameter, however I think I found a method similar to what you say   `re.sub(pattern, lambda m: one_day_or_another_day_relative_to_a_date_func(m, type_of_date_unit_used), input_text, re.IGNORECASE)`